# Tabbar doesn't appears after push back in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, uitabbar

I have a App with a central `UITabbarController` which leads to a `UINavigationController` containing a `UITableViewController` with dynamic cells. If I push on a cell a common `ViewController` appears without the tabbar (I set the property "hideBottomBarOnPush" to YES) through a push segue and of cause you can simply click the "Back" button and you will come back to the `TableViewController`.
The issue is that when the push back action is performed the `UITabbar` from the TabbarController isn't there anymore. I tried to set

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
```

in the viewDidLoad of my TableViewController and set

```
[self.tabBarController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed: NO];
```

in the viewWillDisappear of my ViewController but without success.
Hope someone know the tiny trick to solve the issue.

Comment: Put this two methods in `viewWillAppear` method in the tabBarViewController class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` method in your case won't be called when returning from your `TableViewControler` as you `TabBarViewController` is already in the memory.

Put this two methods in `viewWillAppear` instead as this will be called every time view controller is about to be displayed to user.

Comment: Wow okay thank you very much that solved the problem! I am very shocked from myself that I didn't noticed this stupid mistake.